# RTK Query: Can you safely mutate useQuery data?

Tags: rtk-query

I'm integrating with RTK Toolkit, and in the tutorial they give this example:

```
export const PostsList = () => {
  const {
    data: posts = [],
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error
  } = useGetPostsQuery()

  const sortedPosts = useMemo(() => {
    const sortedPosts = posts.slice()
    // Sort posts in descending chronological order
    sortedPosts.sort((a, b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date))
    return sortedPosts
  }, [posts])
```

They explain it with

> We can't just call `posts.sort()` directly, because `Array.sort()` mutates the existing array, so we'll need to make a copy of it first.

My question is how accurate is it? Would mutating `data` actually mutate the value in the cache, affecting other calls to `useGetPostsQuery`? Or is it just recommending copying it based off of best practices?

edit: I posted this question a bit too soon. I just tried out directly reversing it, and I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: 0 is read-only`. I'd still like to understand what's going on behind the scenes here if anyone knows how it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is - like every value you get from a Redux store - a direct reference to the value in the store. So if you could sort that array, it would also sort the store - but without a way for Redux to notice that mutation, so your UI would not immediately update in other places and you would run into weird inconsistencies over time.

That said, as you have noticed, RTK uses `immer` and `immer` auto-freezes values outside of reducers, so you can't accidentally mutate them.

Comment: Wait, `like every value you get from a Redux store`.. so useSelector returns a reference to the actual state in Redux in general? I guess that makes sense, otherwise they'd have to do a lot of copying. TIL! Immer is pretty cool, it's interesting how it freezes it.

Comment: Yup, that's also true for `useSelector`. The freezing eliminates a whole class of very hard to track bugs ;)